# how to replace and add style into specific tag

Tags: php, regex

i have a problem. i can't replace and add inline style css.
i have this
 **input:**

```
<p  style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-size: 11pt;">hello world<br /></span></p>
<p id="tem" style="text-align: justify;">test</p>
<p >&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

and i want this 
**output:**

```
<p style="text-align: justify;margin:0;"><span style="font-size: 11pt;">hello world<br /></span></p>
<p id="tem" style="text-align: justify;margin:0;">test</p>
<p  style="margin:0;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="margin:0;">&nbsp;</p>
```

i have tried this way [demo](http://regex101.com/r/wE8bN2/1)

```
 $re = "/(<p[^>]+\")([^>\"]+)/miu";
    $str = "<p id=\"tem\" style=\"text-align: justify;\"><span style=\"font-size: 11pt;\">hello world<br /></span></p>\n<p style=\"text-align: justify;\">test</p>\n<p >&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>";
    $subst = "$1$2margin:0;";

    $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

please help me anybody. thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using `DOM`?

Comment: no, only preg_replace.

Comment: last 2 line is not match & not replace. please see **demo**

Comment: Why can't you just modify the string yourself?

Comment: @self i do not know advance regex

Comment: I mean why do you have to use a regex to change a string?

Comment: for faster, if use DOM then may be little slow. because it works with huge data. 5-10 email content in same time. another cause: can have missing some tag

Comment: premature optimization is nothing but waste of time. use XMLReader class instantiation on you xml http://stackoverflow.com/a/15374109/1593365

Comment: please give me a answer or solution for my expected output with example..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have solved that:**

search by regex pattern `((?<=\<)[^>]+style=")([^>"]+)`  and replace with `$1$2margin:0;`

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/wE8bN2/2)